# Applying numpy masks with multiple matching criteria

Tags: python, numpy

I am a python newbie, trying to understand how to work with numpy masks better.
I have two 2D data arrays plus axis values, so something like

```
        import numpy as np 
        data1=np.arange(50).reshape(10,5)
        data2=np.random.rand(10,5)
        x=5*np.arange(5)+15
        y=2*np.arange(10)
```

Where x contains the coordinates of the 1st axis of data1 and data2, and y gives the coordinates of the 2nd axis of data1 and data2.

I want to identify and count all the points in data1 for which

1. data1>D1min,
2. the corresponding x values are inside a given range, XRange, and
3. the corresponding y is are inside a given range, YRange

Then, when I am all done, I also need to do a check to make sure none of the corresponding data2 values are less than another limit, D2Max

so if

```
        XRange = [27,38]
        YRange = [2,12]
        D1min = 23
        D2Max = 0.8
```

I would want to include cells 3:4 in the x direction and 1:6 in the 2nd dimension (assuming I want to include the limiting values).

That means I would only consider data1[3:4,1:6]
Then the limits of the values in the 2D arrays come into it, so want to identify and count points for which data1[3:4,1:6] > 23.

Once I have done that I want to take *those* data locations and check to see if any of those locations have values <0.8 in data2.

In reality I don't have formulas for x and y, and the arrays are much larger. Also, x and y might not even be monotonic.

I figure I *should* use numpy masks for this and I have managed to do it, but the result seems really tortured - I think the code wold be more clear if I just looped though the values in the 2D arrays.

I think the main problem is that I have trouble combining masks with boolean operations. The ideas I get from searching on line often don't seem to work on arrays.

I assume there is a elegant and (hopefully) understandable way to do this in just a few lines with masks. Would anyone care to explain it to me?

Comment: Your sentence `"all the points in data1 for which data1>D1min x is inside XRange y is inside YRange"` isn't particularly clear, please rephrase with proper grammar, punctuation, and ideally, also provide a simple example input and desired output.

Comment: For instance, what does `"x is inside XRange"` have to do with the data in `data1`?

Comment: Sorry about that. I have rewritten it trying to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Well I eventually came up with something, so I thought I'd post it. I welcome suggested improvements.

```
#expand x and y into 2D arrays so that they can more 
#easily be used for masking using tile
x2D = np.tile(x,(len(y),1))
y2D = np.tile(y,(len(x),1)).T

#mask these based on the ranges in X and Y
Xmask = np.ma.masked_outside(x2D,XRange[0],XRange[1]).mask
Ymask = np.ma.masked_outside(y2D,YRange[0],YRange[1]).mask

#then combine them
#Not sure I need the shrink=False, but it seems safer
XYmask = np.ma.mask_or(Xmask, Ymask,shrink=False)

#now mask the data1 array based on D1mask. 
highdat = np.ma.masked_less(data1,D1min)

#combine with XYmask
data1mask = np.ma.mask_or(highdat.mask, XYmask,shrink=False) 

#apply to data1 
data1masked = np.ma.masked_where(data1mask,data1)

#number of points fulfilling my criteria
print('Number of points: ',np.ma.count(data1masked))

#transfer mask from data1 to data2
data2masked = np.ma.masked_where(data1mask, data2)
   
#do my check based on data2
if data2masked.min() < D2Max: print('data2 values are low!')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).